# convert list to nested dic and assign a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert csv to Json. If I encounter csv headers with naming convention `"columnName1.0.columnName2.0.columnName3"` I need to create a nested JSON --> `{ColumnName1 : {columnName2 : {columnName3 : value }}}`..

So far I am able to split header into list of subColumnNames and create a nested JSON type, but I am unable to assign a value. Any Help?

```
    data = open(str(fileName.strip("'")),'rb')
    reader = csv.DictReader(data,delimiter = ',',quotechar='"')

    ''' 
        Get the header '''

    for line in reader:
        for x,y in line.items():
            columns = re.split("\.\d\.",x)
            if len(columns) == 1:
                continue
            else:
                print "COLUMNS %s"%columns
                testLine = {}
                for subColumnName in reversed(columns):
                    testLine = {subColumnName: testLine}
                ''' Need to Assign value y? '''    
                print "LINE%s"%testLine
```

Output:

```
COLUMNS ['experience', 'title']
LINE{'experience': {'title': {}}}
COLUMNS ['experience', 'organization', 'profile_url']
LINE{'experience': {'organization': {'profile_url': {}}}}
COLUMNS ['experience', 'start']
LINE{'experience': {'start': {}}}
COLUMNS ['raw_experience', 'organization', 'profile_url']
LINE{'raw_experience': {'organization': {'profile_url': {}}}}
COLUMNS ['raw_experience', 'end']
LINE{'raw_experience': {'end': {}}}
COLUMNS ['experience', 'organization', 'name']
LINE{'experience': {'organization': {'name': {}}}}
```

Comment: What is preventing you from assigning a value? i.e. are you not sure how to assign to the nest-dict you just created? Could you make your question more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you want is currently `{}`, the initial value of `testLine`.  You can try this:

```
testLine = value
for subColumnName in reversed(columns):
    testLine = {subColumnName: testLine}
```